# Is it common practice to turn on GC logging in production Java server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, garbage-collection, jvm

I see in a few places [1] people start the GC logging in production servers (mission critical), e.g.

```
java -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m \
     -XX:MaxNewSize=256m \
     -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC \
     -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
     -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
     -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps \
     -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution \
     -Xloggc:logs/gc.log \
     -Djava.awt.headless=true
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -classpath ...
```

Is it recommend practices in production env these days?

**Update**: I have included a link [2] from Oracle also suggest to monitor GC on production servers.

Sources:

[1] https://serverfault.com/questions/121490/java-opts-xxprintgcdetails-affect-on-performance

[2] http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22838/deploy_checklist.htm#CHHFADDF

Comment: I haven't seen it...I wonder what that would tell you as opposed to...say, an actual logging framework, though.

Comment: @Makoto an "actual logging framework" wont log GC times.

Comment: Yes, but I question the validity of such information.  If the system is mission critical, or needs to run in a narrow timeframe, then it would be more beneficial to benchmark the key components which cause high GC times.

Comment: @Makoto - it depends what you are trying to achieve.  If you are trying to tune the GC ... or even monitor it ... then profiling / benchmarking won't help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Yes**, this is a common practice. This is **often highly recommended** and I give examples and references below.

Why GC logging is good for production Java servers:

1. **Minimal Overhead** - The GC logging has a **minimal overhead** to the overall system performance.

   - This is claimed e.g. by Charlie Hunt, ex-JVM Performance Architect and co-author of the [Java Performance book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137142528).
   - all the [world record SPEC Benchmarks](http://www.spec.org/jEnterprise2010/results/jEnterprise2010.html) running Java Enterprise software are running production servers with GC logging enabled. This confirms that the logging has low overhead and also that the logging path is highly tuned by the performace experts publishing the benchmark results.
2. **Long-term logging** is absolutely **crucial to** the analysis of the **Application Performance**. The GC logging must be enabled all the time so that the Administrators are able to observe the GC behavior and tune the application accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (I really like people answering with evidence and not just personal opinion.)

Comment: Minimal overhead isn't quite true if you encounter a flush during a log write and there's I/O activity impacting disk performance. This is made worse in JDK 9 and later by Unified Logging flushing on every event. See:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/asynchronous-logging-corretto-17/
https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/02/eliminating-large-jvm-gc-pauses-caused-by-background-io-traffic

Answer (score -4):

Definitely not.

You would only load the prod server in this way if there was an issue that couldn't be reproduced on your QA system. And even then only for a short period to collect data then return to normal "lean" mode.

Comment: I am afraid that his is not correct. GC logging is often recommended by the JVM Performance engineers and architects, see my answer.