# How to hold 5GB constantly memory in application without suffering from poor performance due to GC?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

My app is geo application.
Due to a requirement of short response time each of my instance load all points to memory and store them in a structure (quad tree).

Every minute we load all points (to be sync with the db) and put them in few quad trees.

We now have 0.5GB points.
I am trying to prepare to the next level of 5GB points.
JVM:
-XX:NewSize=6g -Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -verboseGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails

Startup of the instance took lots of times due to GC in additional the app suffer from GC all the time.

I would like to have some reference to GC with large heap.

I can think of few solutions for this:

1. To refresh only the changes in the db and not load all db each time. **Cons** - still will suffer from GC during the early stage of the application, Long time GC.
2. Off heap solution. Store in the quad tree the point ids and store the points out of heap. **Cons** - serialization time, the geo structure is a complex of few objects and not simple object.
3. For each instance create additional instance with the structure and query against this instance . The geo instance will hold long lived object and can have GC adjustment for long lived object. **Cons** - complexity and response time.

Any references to article on apps that hold few GIG of long lived objects will be more than welcome.

Run on Ubuntu (Amazon). Java 7 . Dosnt have memory limitation.

The problem is long pause time each time we refresh the data.
[image: Gc]

Gc log for the refresh:

```
2014-06-15T16:32:58.551+0000: 1037.469: [GC2014-06-15T16:32:58.551+0000: 1037.469: [ParNew: 5325855K->259203K(5662336K), 0.0549830 secs] 16711893K->11645244K(20342400K), 0.0551490 secs] [Times: user=0.71 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:02.383+0000: 1041.302: [GC2014-06-15T16:33:02.383+0000: 1041.302: [ParNew: 5292419K->470768K(5662336K), 0.0851740 secs] 16678460K->11856811K(20342400K), 0.0853260 secs] [Times: user=1.09 sys=0.00, real=0.09 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:06.114+0000: 1045.033: [GC2014-06-15T16:33:06.114+0000: 1045.033: [ParNew: 5503984K->629120K(5662336K), 1.5475170 secs] 16890027K->12193877K(20342400K), 1.5476760 secs] [Times: user=5.49 sys=0.61, real=1.55 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:11.145+0000: 1050.063: [GC2014-06-15T16:33:11.145+0000: 1050.063: [ParNew: 5662336K->558612K(5662336K), 0.7742870 secs] 17227093K->12758866K(20342400K), 0.7744610 secs] [Times: user=3.88 sys=0.82, real=0.77 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:11.920+0000: 1050.838: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 12200254K(14680064K)] 12761216K(20342400K), 0.1407080 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.01, real=0.14 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:12.061+0000: 1050.979: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]

2014-06-15T16:33:14.208+0000: 1053.127: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 2.148/2.148 secs] [Times: user=19.46 sys=0.44, real=2.15 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:14.208+0000: 1053.127: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]

2014-06-15T16:33:14.232+0000: 1053.150: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.023/0.023 secs] [Times: user=0.14 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:14.232+0000: 1053.150: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]

2014-06-15T16:33:15.629+0000: 1054.548: [GC2014-06-15T16:33:15.630+0000: 1054.548: [ParNew: 5591828K->563654K(5662336K), 0.1279360 secs] 17792082K->12763908K(20342400K), 0.1280840 secs] [Times: user=1.65 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs] 

2014-06-15T16:33:19.143+0000: 1058.062: [GC2014-06-15T16:33:19.143+0000: 1058.062: [ParNew: 5596870K->596692K(5662336K), 0.3445070 secs] 17797124K->13077191K(20342400K), 0.3446730 secs] [Times: user=3.06 sys=0.34, real=0.35 secs] 

 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2014-06-15T16:33:19.832+0000: 1058.750: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 5.124/5.600 secs] [Times: user=35.91 sys=1.67, real=5.60 secs]
```

Comment: How do you know that the GC is the one to blame? What are you doing with the quad tree? Testing points? Is your quad-tree balanced?

Comment: I am using vivid solution for the quad. I can see in the GC logs the time that the application spent in GC. During the startup when i load the db the app is spent lot of time in GC.

Comment: "Every minute we load all points " - why not just the changes?

Comment: While it may sound that the GC is to blame here, I imagine your performance problems have more to do from the fact you are allocating 2GB points each minute.

Comment: Also, the whole point of using a spatial index like a quad tree, is that you don't need to hold everything in memory! :)

Comment: In 0.5GIG we didnt have GC problem so we refresh the whole DB. In 5 GIG we will load only changes but as i mention in 1 in the early stage of the application it spent lot of time in GC (until object moved from Eden) and in the later stage GC is long due to big heap.

Comment: Sorry its 5 GIG not 2 GIG . I wrote 2 GIG by mistake.

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Big-Memory-Part-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to tune the JVM play with the new size, heap size ...
Also tried G1 (-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200) without success and got pretty soon OOM.

Eventually the solution was to load only changes.
When load only changes the GC pause time was only 0.55% and average pause time was 17.3ms.

When load all the data you dont have concurrent issues, because you dont need to lock the serving class structures (quad,maps) while updating, because you create a new serving class and as soon that the new serving class is ready to serve you update the reference of the serving class with the updated one.
In order to still avoid locking on the serving data we create a new serving class based on the old data and merge to it the updated data, so 99.9% of the data that was load before and exist in the old generation will not need to be clean . The gc will clean only the quad-trees references and the map keys references and it will be cleaned by CMS.

If you must completely refresh you data dont do it in one time. Try to break your data to few structures and once in a while refresh each data structure in this case the GC will suffer from much less pauses time and expensive failures.

If you must do it in one time and you can afford long pauses than create a small newsize ,so the object will passed to the old gen.

In our test there is constant load by 6 thread and every 3 minutes we load 3.5G of serving data and replace the old one.
A test that was done with : 
-XX:NewSize=6g -Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Yield:
[image: GC 6G newsize]

GC happened less often (Mean interval between collections (ms)  3735) , but most of them take around 4 secs.

When change to:
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -Xms20g -Xmx20g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

Yield:
[image: GC with small new size]

Answer (score 2):

People have made some very good comments on design points above that you should definitely consider. If you consider GC implications only your question is a little bit tricky to answer, as Garbage Collection tuning is not an exact science. What you may wish to consider is that actual GC algorithm that you are using. But a little background first:

Garbage collection is generational and it's performance relies on the [high infant mortality](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc-tuning-5-138395.html#1.1.%20Generations%7Coutline) rate of objects - that is objects are created and rapidly destroyed during the application flow. You are holding onto large objects (due to the caching nature), that means you will be filling up Eden and GC will be required to promote those objects to survivor and tenured spaces.

[image: Hotspot Heap Structure]

This would mean that should you ever need to reclaim this memory it is likely to be in tenured and therefore require a longer GC pause time to collect. However, given the size of your heap this might not be a problem as it may never need to do a full GC. A healthy application is **expected to frequently GC** for a very short amount of time to collect Eden, so don't get too distracted by the garbage collector kicking in. However do get concerned by a Full GC. If you haven't got you garbage collector logs turned on now is the time to do so, as this will allow you to measure and not make assumptions if you are already.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307998/is-it-common-practice-to-turn-on-gc-logging-in-production-java-server) for more details.

From Java 7 update 4 you can use the G1 garbage collector. This algorithm is specifically designed to work with large heaps on multicore machines. When you start your application you would use something like this command:

```
java -Xmx50m -Xms50m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
```

This allows you to specify your heap size and a target performance that you are looking to achieve. G1 works slightly different to the mark and sweep algorithm used by default in that it looks across the heap at different regions and tries to claim areas that have mostly garbage in. Fully reclaimable segments of the heap are cheap to reclaim so it will find as many of these as possible and collect them within your desired pause time. It does as much of this as possible in parallel leveraging your multicores to avoid wasting time during stop the world.

[image: G1 Garbage Collector]

It is certainly not guaranteed that G1 is going to be the silver bullet for your problem, but with your traits you might find it works really well for you (as things that are not needed in the cache can be removed easier and are likely to be located closely due to principal of locality). There is some beginner information on G1 [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/index.html). Also take a look at this [article](http://www.insightfullogic.com/blog/2013/jun/24/garbage-collection-java-4/) that goes into a lot more depth that I have here.

Comment: This is great explanation on how GC work (Already know it), but dosnt answer specific to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I thought it would be wort adding that if your application is using a lot of caching, you can benefit from a larger young generation size.  For some reason, this is rarely recommended but I've had some really good results with this in a caching use case.  The best place for objects to die is in the young generation.  There is basically no cost to collecting objects in young.  The worst thing that can happen is that you have objects that live just long enough to move to the tenured space and then promptly die.

There are two ways around this in hotspot.

1. increase the tenuring threshold: this is the number of minor GC cycles before an object will be promoted giving these objects more time to die in the young generation
2. increase the size of the young generation.  Minor collections will occur less frequently and therefore there is more time for objects to die in the young generation.

If you have a lot of memory to play with, I would try allocating a very large amount to the young generation.  Try giving the young generation at least twice what you expect to be alive in the cache at any time.  Leave the tenuring threshold at 2 at first.

Using a setup like this, we've been running an cache server (Infinispan) for over a month with no major collections.  Minor collections run about every hour and max out at 0.2 seconds pause to collect 6-7 GB of garbage.  The live set is approximately 1GB at any given time.  It's this live set that will primarily determines the time it will take so increasing the young generation further will reduce collections but should not change the pause times much.

In an application that is doing other things aside from caching, this might not work perfectly.  In my case the tenured space is holding steady at around 120MB.  Ideally, you'll have enough space for your long-lived objects and only have to move stuff to tenured once.  Depending on the application, this might be difficult to pull off.